# Merging two simple javascript functions into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, merge

I have the following code in my index.html for an input field:

```
<input id="inpMinutes" type="number" style="width: 50px; text-align: right" min="1" value="1" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
<span id="minuteS">minute</span>
```

I want to keep the entered number between 1 and 600 without allowing entering any non digit characters. This is done by 2 different functions in my main.js file, but I would like to merge them, but I am very noob at javascript, I just stole and modified this code.

```
// keep out non-digits from the input field that calls this
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}

$("#inpMinutes").on("input", function() {
    // do not allow to enter a number less than 1 into the minutes field (minus sign is prevented by isNumberKey())
    if ( this.value == 0 ) {
        this.value = 1;
    // do not allow to enter a number larger than 600
    } else if ( this.value > 600 ) {
        this.value = 600;
    }
    // make the "minute" word grammatically correct
    if ( this.value > 1 ) {
        minuteS.innerHTML = "minutes";
    } else {
        minuteS.innerHTML = "minute";
    }
});
```

What is the most elegant (most efficient?) way to merge these into one single function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is separate because the second function is jquery.

Comment: I think you shouldn't, for a couple of reasons. a) They serve different purposes. Best practise is to keep a function single-purpose. b) They are called on different occasions. Key blocking is done as you type, while input validation is usually done onblur (very annoying if you do that while typing). c) Be aware that you can still *paste* invalid characters, so you should validate the input anyway. So: always validate the entire string on blur to check for invalid characters.

Comment: Suggestion solution: set [`type=number`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/) to make (some) browsers enforce the numbers itself, and always validate yourself. Still, this is not guaranteed, so you should validate again on 'input', and also validate again on the server. Life is a female dog...

Comment: The type is already set to number, but when I tested it, it didn't want to work (using the latest firefox and chrome). Yeah, maybe you are right that it is better to keep them separated, I was also thinking about the possibility that later I may need to call only one of them from another input field (for example). I haven't met this onblur thing yet, but I like better the instant correction than the other case, when correction is done only when the input field is left. (I tried to paste invalid string into the field but I was not able.) I like your answers, learned something from them, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/20m6eLxx/

HTML

```
<input id="inpMinutes" type="number" min="1" value="1" data-oldvalue="1" data-regex="^([0-9]{1,2}|[1-5][0-9]{2}|600)$" />
<span id="minuteS">minute</span>
```

JS

```
$('#inpMinutes').on('input', function (e) {
    var $target = $(e.target),
            val = $target.val(),
            rgx = new RegExp($target.attr('data-regex'));

    if (!rgx.test(val)) {
        $target.val($target.attr('data-oldvalue'));
        return;
    }
    $target.attr('data-oldvalue', $target.val());
    $('#minuteS').html(val > 1 ? 'minutes' : 'minute');
});
```

To preserve the behavior of showing the max value when a >max value is typed, see this update: https://jsfiddle.net/20m6eLxx/1/

---

You *could* also generify this a little bit if you wanted to, extending it to all inputs that need validation and restricted keying, by broadening your selector, e.g.:

```
//<input class="restricted others" data-regex="etc." />
$('.restricted').on('input', function (e) {...... 
or
//for any input that has the data-regex attribute
$('input[data-regex]').on('input', function (e) {......
```

**A small piece of advice**

Unless you really know what you're doing, please be very considerate towards cancelling event defaults and bubbling. I've broken a few keyboards as a result of rage when tabs, ctrl + modifiers etc. didn't work because of extremely unthoughtful key blocking. It's a usability disaster unless well thought out, and well thought out is usually rare when it comes to forms and validation (imho).

Comment: This looks cool. (Only one mistake I could find: you should have used "val > 1" instead of "val > 60") Thanks for your advice, I havent thought about those things yet, but as I tested, for example Tab works in the field (I can leave it with Tab), also backspace and arrows work too, and I don't need more. I probably will use this solution, but now I am going to sleep and will check back tomorrow. :)

Comment: @Tom Ah yes, well spotted - corrected. I was thinking "seconds" all the time, for some reason. And the reason tab and other keys work is because I didn't touch the event propagation at any point. Cheers.

Comment: I am interested in generifying the checks, because I will need to use these kinds of checks later, but I just don't know (yet) how to use these $('.restricted') and $('[data-regex]') things... How should the HTML code looke like in those cases? And one more question: I kinda like in my original code, that when I press the number "1" four times in the field, it doesn't stop at "111", but the number is lowered down from "1111" to "600". How can I achieve this with your code? Thanks very much!

Comment: @Tom Link added for preserving that behavior. Simple clause inside the regex rejector. Check the new fidddle. Add a max attribute to the element, and that little clause inside the first regex checking block. https://jsfiddle.net/20m6eLxx/1/

Comment: @Tom Also, HTML snippets added in the code (see answer) for those selectors you asked about.

Comment: Thanks, @BluePill, the answers you provided are great. I will use these codes. :)

Comment: I have one more question, @BluePill, I hope you get some kind of notification about this... I am using your code and I am struggling to modify it to put commas at every 3rd number counting from the left. How can I achieve this with your code? I am sure there must be an easy way, I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

why not move the entire login to the isNumberKey function. Build the to be value by merging the character stroke to the input value to check whether it stays in range and make the "minute" word grammatically correct, then return false to prevent the propagation, counting on only what you've set explicitly.

Comment: This was my first thought, but I didn't know (still don't know) how to do it, because for example I have no clue what this line is doing: "var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode" Ok, I can guess, but I don't know the exact details. It is some kind of if/else I guess... And I also don't know hot to check the value of the field.